# Exception Test by Mocking: An Unexpected success

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking

Testing using Mock object. I implemented an usecase to return InvalidInputException(Custom) if the email is duplicated at the time of registration.

```java
    /**
     * 이메일 중복 체크
     *
     * <ol>
     * <li>회원가입 이메일 중복 확인</li>
     * </ol>
     *
     * @param UserSignupCommand
     */
    void checkDuplicated(UserSignupCommand signup);
```

```java
    @Override
    public void checkDuplicated(UserSignupCommand signup) {
        Optional<User> user = signupCommandPort.findByEmail(signup.getEmail());
        if (user.isPresent())
            throw new InvalidInputException("이미 존재하는 이메일입니다.");
    }
```

The test result of the usecase successfully returns InvalidInputException. However, there was a problem when I tried to test the Controller.

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("회원가입 이메일 중복 확인 테스트")
    public void UserDuplicateTest() {
        UserSignupCommand command = UserSignupCommand.builder()
                .email("user@user.dev")
                .password("qwer1234")
                .passwordVerify("qwer1234")
                .build();

        when(userSignupCommandPort.findByEmail(command.getEmail()))
        .thenReturn(Optional.of(User.builder().build()));
        
        assertThrowsExactly(InvalidInputException.class, () ->
        signupService.checkDuplicated(command), "");
        
        verify(userSignupCommandPort, times(1)).findByEmail(any());
    }
```

[image]

Here's Controller Test Code:

```java
@Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    SignupUsecase signupService;
    
    @MockBean
    UserSignupCommandPort userSignupCommandPort;
    
    @MockBean
    JwtService jwtService;

    @MockBean
    TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    private SignupRequest dto;

    @BeforeEach
    void initDto() {
        dto = new SignupRequest(
                "dean",
                "user@user.dev",
                "1234qwer",
                "1234qwer"
                );
    }
```

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("이메일 중복 검사 시 실패 테스트")
    public void checkDuplicated_fail() throws Exception {
        when(userSignupCommandPort.findByEmail(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(User.builder().build()));
        
        assertThrowsExactly(UserSignupException.class, () -> signupService.checkDuplicated(any()), "");
        
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/auth/signup/checkDuplicated")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
//              .andExpect(jsonPath("$.code", equalTo("ERROR"))); // It must be ERROR
        
    }
```

I set up the Defalut Exception Handler so that a jsonPath is passed to the body in the event of an exception.
It goes with "ERROR" of "SUCCESS" by the value of the key "code".
But, even the exception, the key is always return "SUCCESS". What should I do?

[image]
[image]

I was checked the MockBean, I thought if it imported a interface, it doesn't import even it is implemented.
this thing wasn't solve the problem I guess.

---

puls:

different type of parameter objects problem:
I used lambda function to change object type.

```java
    @PostMapping("/checkDuplicated")
    public void checkDuplicated(@RequestBody SignupRequest dto) {
        signupService.checkDuplicated(commandMapper.apply(dto));
    }

    Function<SignupRequest, UserSignupCommand> commandMapper = req -> new UserSignupCommand(
            req.getName(),
            req.getEmail(),
            req.getPassword(),
            req.getPasswordVerify());
```

check thrown exceptions:

I checked if it throws exception with assertThorwsExactly.
It's Ok at an usecase test, but there's problem at cotroller test.

Usecase Test:
[image]

Controller Test:
[image]

Comment: Show your controller code plus your ControllerAdvise.  Also just so you know,  you are mocking when(userSignupCommandPort.findByEmail(dto.getEmail())).thenThrow(new InvalidInputException("Duplicated email")) and the type of DTO is SignUpRequest, but at the first code example had a different type of UserSignupCommand.   I suggest you double check that you are mocking the correct method with the correct input.

Comment: @JCompetence thack you. I updated my post. and I also checked different content objects problem.  I changed to use any().

Comment: You are now doing     when(userSignupCommandPort.findByEmail(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(User.builder().build())); which means that when this method is called, then return a User.  Try thenReturn(Optional.empty()) and see if that works. Also put a debug statement inside that method to see if it does in fact go inside that method in the controller.

Comment: @JCompetence I finally found it. the repository doesn't get Optional Object when it calls "userSignupCommandPort.findByEmail()" but I used .get() in repository method. there's the problem. I changed .get() to orElse(null).